# How does Facebook Messenger iPhone app gets login information from Facebook iPhone app?

Tags: ios, objective-c

If you have both Facebook iPhone app and Facebook messenger app installed in your iPhone, I noticed that, as long as you are logged in in the Facebook app, Facebook messenger app knows who you are immediately!

How did facebook do that?

How do two applications talk to each other?

I am interested to know this because I want to know if it is possible for two applications to share some common data (e.g. products database) so that those data only has to be updated in one app.

Answer (score 2):

A suite of iOS applications can use Keychain Access sharing to share credential information. You cannot, however, share a database on the device. You would need to either create one monolithic app, or store the shared data off-device.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna take a guess but I think they storage your UDID in their DBs with the current logged user

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is done using Single Sign-On (SSO) feature of the Facebook iOS SDK. According to the facebook developer documentation, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#implementsso,
it states that if the user already has the Facebook app of version greater than 3.2.3 installed and that the iOS device of the user supports multitasking, then basically the app (the facebook messenger in this case) can ask for the current logged in user information from the main Facebook program.

"One of the most compelling features of the iOS SDK is Single-Sign-On (SSO). SSO lets users sign into your app using their Facebook identity. If they are already signed into the Facebook iOS app on their device they do not have to even type a username and password. Further, because they are signing to your app with their Facebook identity, you can get permission from the user to access to their profile information and social graph"

"If the app is running in a version of iOS that supports multitasking, and if the device has the Facebook app of version 3.2.3 or greater installed, the SDK attempts to open the authorization dialog within the Facebook app. After the user grants or declines the authorization, the Facebook app redirects back to the calling app, passing the authorization token, expiration, and any other parameters the Facebook OAuth server may return."

Comment: This isn't entirely true though.  If you notice, the facebook messenger does not redirect to the facebook app as the documentation suggests that SSO will do (I also tested that this is the bahvior that spotify does).  I'm guessing Ben's answer is actually correct, since they probably store something on the KeyChain.